# What is the formula for calculating adjusted closing price after a rights issue?

Tags: backtesting, historical-data

I know how to calculate adjusted closing prices in case of splits, dividends, etc but I'm not able to figure out how it's done in case of a rights issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical rights issue is of the form:

A rights for every B shares at a price of C, where the closing price on the day prior to ex-rights date is D.

To calculate a dilution factor from a rights issue:
( a*c/(a+b) + b*d/(a+b) ) / d

In python code form:

```
# Rights issue - 1 for 4 rights issue at $18 with previous close of $20
a = 1
b = 4
c = 18
d = 20

dilutionfactor = ( a*c/(a+b) + b*d/(a+b) ) / d

# the dilution factor calculated here here is 0.98
```

All prices prior to the ex-rights date need to be multiplied by this factor.

In the above example, this would make the adjusted price on the day prior to the ex-rights date $19.60.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In NSE (Indian stock exchange), the closing price of the day is not the same as the market price (last trader price). In that case I'm assuming we have to use that instead of closing price as D because that way I'm getting much more accurate prices (even though there's still a little difference and I can't figure out know why).

Comment: From what I can see, there's a separate session on NSE that lasts for 20 minutes after the regular trading session.  This session is basically an auction session.  Other markets do this too (e.g. ASX, which has a 10 minute single closing price auction).  If no trades occur as a result of the auction, then the previous trade is the closing trade.  The official closing price is the one used by corporate action providers.

Comment: Actually in NSE the daily closing price is calculated as the VWAP of the last 30 minutes of the regular session. I'm getting accurate prices using the last traded price with your formula. There's still a small difference but I guess it's close enough. When I use the closing price, the results are way off.

Comment: The adjujstment calculation is there for you to determine a reasonable model for  the rate of return.  High levels of volatility around such events makes such adjustments less logical.

Comment: Regarding NSE, I still stand by the "Closing Session" auction that occurs 15:40-16:00.    https://www.nseindia.com/products-services/equity-market-timings-holidays - I can't find any reference to 30 min VWAP for equities trading on NSE India.

Comment: Here is info on how the closing price is calculated. https://support.zerodha.com/category/trading-and-markets/trading-faqs/articles/ltp-doesnt-match-close

Comment: Zerodha is not NSE.  Did you actually look at the NSE links describing how they do things?

Comment: I'm well aware that Zerodha is not NSE, thank you very much. One is a broker and the other is an exchange. I was also already aware of the existence of a closing session even before you posted your link. I'm trying to tell you that the closing price in NSE is not calculated based on what happens in the closing session. The closing price is calculated at 3:30 as the VWAP of the last 30 minutes and any orders placed in the closing session from 3:40 to 4:00 get executed as market orders at the already calculated and fixed closing price. Did YOU actually look at NSE describing how they do things?

Comment: Also, Zerodha is the biggest broker in the country and I'm pretty sure they know what they're talking about. You're just giving a link saying a closing session exists from 3:40 to 4:00. The discussion is not about whether a closing session exists or not. It's about how the closing price is calculated.

Comment: If you want to know more. https://support.zerodha.com/category/trading-and-markets/trading-faqs/articles/what-are-pre-market-and-post-market-sessions-and-orders

Comment: OK - so it appears that the "closing session" is badly named.  Other exchanges refer to a "closing single price auction" which actually sets the closing price.  So, the closing session on NSE just gives you the ability to transact at the "closing price".  Now, let's try and find the NSE methodology for "closing price"

Comment: Clearly the information out there varies.  This describes an auction (per my original methodology) in the closing session:  https://www.outlookindia.com/outlookmoney/archive/closing-prices-86306

Comment: I already read that article and it's an article from 1999. Things haven't been that way since a long time. That article even has the wrong timings of the closing session. It says 3:35 to 3:50 instead of 3:40 to 4:00.

Comment: This link describes a closing price calculation session of 15:30-15:40, prior to the "closing session", but this is not referenced on NSE web site.   https://tradebrains.in/stock-market-timings-in-india/

Comment: That link basically says the same thing I've been saying all this time. The NSE website itself is not very user-friendly sometimes when it comes to finding critical information. That's the reason I've been linking to Zerodha's website.

Comment: You need to raise this with NSE.  It should be very clear to everyone (investors, traders etc.)  about how a closing price is determined.  Other exchanges worldwide have defined this very clearly in their rules/regulations.

Comment: @pale_rider - Did you manage to find the exact methodology to calculate adjusted price after right issue? The price I calculate is always different from TradingView or Zerodha.